# How do I push only my first X local commits to SVN using hgsubversion?

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

I'm currently using hgsubversion on a project to enjoy the benefits of local commits while the project's official SCM is Subversion. In order to push local commits to the SVN repo, I've been using `hg rebase --svn` followed by a simple `hg push` with successful results thus far.

One small hiccup I've run into is that if I have a certain fix for something that I'd like to push, without pushing everything else, I *thought* I could just commit that fix and then push it. But this gives me the following message:

> abort: outstanding uncommitted changes

OK, fine. So I shelve my uncommitted changes. But for some reason, I'm unable to shelve one particular change (added a new file). I figure, what the heck, I can just commit this as it won't really do any harm.

So that's what I do. But then I see that `hg push` can take an `-r` flag which, according to the help documentation, has this effect:

> If -r/--rev is used, the specified revision and all its ancestors will be pushed to the remote repository.

Great! So that sounds like exactly what I want. Now say my latest two local commits are given revision numbers 94 and 95. I thought I could do `hg push -r 94`  and only push the *first* commit to SVN while the second remains a pure local commit. But for some reason this pushed both 94 and 95.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's a bug (or more accurately, a known unimplemented feature): https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issues/243/hg-push-r-rev-to-subversion-does-not-only

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the mq extension enabled:

```
hg qimport -r95:
hg qpop -a
hg push
hg qpush -a
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with Hg, but this is what you can do:

```
hg up -r 94
hg rebase --svn
hg push --svn
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try this next time.